# Remove last digit from number

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write  `dropLastDigit :: Integer -> Integer`

Eg `dropLastDigit 123 == 12` and `dropLastDigit` with any single digit returns 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just divide the number by ten.

```
dropLastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
dropLastDigit n = div n 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dropLastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
dropLastDigit n  
        | (abs n) < 10 = 0
        | otherwise = read $ init $ show n
```